# Помогите со строками Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Дана строка, в которой есть слово «или». Определить, сколько раз оно встречается.

```
a='Дана строка, в которой или есть слово или.'
k=0
m='или'
b=len(a)
for i in range(0,b-1):
 if m in a:
    k=k+1
print("ИЛИ встречается ", k)
```

Выдает 42(
еще вариант:

```
a='Дана строка, в или которой есть слово или.'
k=0
index=a.find('или')
k=k+1
print("ИЛИ встречается ", k)
```

Выдает почему-то 1

Comment: Вы попробуйте на бумажке порисовать. Сейчас кажется, что вы даже не пытались понять, почему оно не работает

Comment: В первом случае k равно длине строки минус 1 (выдает 41, а не 42, как вы пишете). Во втором случае k просто равно 0+1. В качестве домашнего задания попытайтесь разобраться, почему так. Обратите внимание на строку ``index=a.find('или')`` и задайте себе вопрос - что она делает и для чего вообще в вашем коде нужна. И нужна ли?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Дана строка, в которой или есть слово или."
>>> len(re.findall(r"\bили\b", s, flags=re.I))
2
```

Немного объясню:

1. Выражение `\b` означает границу слова*.
2. Поэтому в строке `s` (которая у нас есть изначально) ищем все совпадения с таким шаблоном: `или` (но только не в начале или конце второго слова).
3. Метод `findall()` возвращает все совпадения.
4. И в результате, чтобы найти количество совпадений, можно просто взять длину списка с этими же совпадениями с помощью `len()`.

[Посмотрите как работает даный пример.](https://regex101.com/r/A1qrhF/2)

P.S. [Подробнее](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-26) о выражении `\b` в python.

> *Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that formally, `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning/end of the string. This means that `r'\bfoo\b'` matches `'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz'` but not `'foobar'` or `'foo3'`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91647/discussion-on-answer-by-entithat----python).